# Как лучше обработать строку JSON, чтобы добавить в адаптер к ListView?

Tags: android, java, json

Строку JSON распарсил, получил JSONArray.

Из него я в цикле выбираю строки:

```
str=JSONArray.getString(i);
```

Получаю строки типа:

```
i
{"a":["Andrey",22,92,172],"t1":[5.15,1.38,142564],"t2":1398618093}
i+1
{"a":["Slava",25,80,170],"t1":[6.15,1.98,142565],"t2":1398615095,"t3":1398615095}
...
```

И не знаю, зачем засовываю их ArrayList `arListPipl.add(str);`.

Дальше я построю красивый listView, состоящий из Андрея, Славы и т.д. с  их именами и параметрами, упорядоченный по первому элементу массива t1.

Мне не хватает опыта накидать верный план действий:

1. В каком виде мне представить мои данные, чтоб они хранились в одном месте и я быстро мог получить значения массива "t1" или "a"?
2. Как и во что упаковать столь разные данные в понятную для адаптера структуру?
3. Какой адаптер выбрать, чтоб я мог сортировать список по первому элементу массива t1?

Comment: леща надо дать тому, кто сервер писал.

Comment: В том плане, что числа должны быть представлены строками?

Comment: В том плане, что у данных отсутствует структура. В каждом массиве должны лежать данные одного типа. В каждом объекте определенного типа дожен быть одинаковый набор полей... Я бы отказался работать с такими данными.    
["Andrey",22,92,172] - как можно в один массив положить строку и числа???

Comment: Как выйти из этой ситуации, если серверную часть поменять я не могу?

Comment: создайте модель данных. Если тут вообще это возможно сделать. И распарсивайте данные в эту модель.